# Проблема с кодировкой строк спарщенных данных

Tags: python, кодировка

Я парсю из этой [страницы](https://timeskz.kz/58581-fifa-obyavila-treh-luchshih-futbolistov-goda.html) заголовок.
И на выходе получаю такие "**крякозяблы**".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код который берет заголовок с страницы:

> ```
> def get_title(html):
>     soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>     title = soup.find('div',{'class':'post_title'}).text
>     print(title)
> ```

Как мне "**преобразовать**" эти "**крякозяблы**" в нормальный заголовок?

Который должен быть таким:

> "ФИФА объявила трёх лучших футболистов года"

**P.S:** Сама кодировка сайта в **`UTF-8`**

**UPD:** Сами эти "**кракозяблы**" текстом

```
Ð¤ÐÐ¤Ð Ð¾Ð±ÑÑÐ²Ð¸Ð»Ð° ÑÑÑÑ Ð»ÑÑÑÐ¸Ñ ÑÑÑÐ±Ð¾Ð»Ð¸ÑÑÐ¾Ð² Ð³Ð¾Ð´Ð°
```

Comment: Не могли бы Вы ваши "кракозяблы" привести текстом?

Comment: В какой кодировке работает консоль, может ли она корректно выводить кириллицу? В win, как я понимаю, по умолчанию кодировка не utf8. Можете попробовать в файл записать текст, чтоб это проверить; если в файле всё нормально - проблема в кодировке консоли

Comment: @МихаилМуругов ,Я мой "крякозяблы" привел текст ниже в вопросе.

Comment: @EurobeatIntensifies,консоль работает корректно это я проверял.Т.к после парсинга заголовка,я пытаюсь записать в БД.А БД ругается на эти "Кракозяблы"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял из комментариев,дело в сервере.То есть при возврате результаты он  указал не правильную кодировку.

Проблема решилась такими строчками кода:

> ```
> def get_html(url):
>     r = requests.get(url)
>     r.encoding = 'utf-8'
>     return r.text
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_title(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    title = soup.find('div',{'class':'post_title'}).text
    print(title)

r = requests.get('https://timeskz.kz/58581-fifa-obyavila-treh-luchshih-futbolistov-goda.html')
r = r.content.decode('utf-8')
get_title(r)  # ФИФА объявила трёх лучших футболистов года
```

Answer (score -1):

Как указал выше @vadim vaduxa, все дело в функции decode. Она из явно указанной кодировки (utf-8) декодирует в unicode. Процедуре print нужно указывать либо кодировку ОС, либо unicode. У виндовой консоли кодировка по умолчанию cp1251 (на 10 вроде точно она), если я не ошибаюсь. А лучше всего не гадать, и все строки декодировать в unicode. Подробнее лучше почитать об этом тут: https://habr.com/ru/post/135913/

Comment: Вообще не рядом. В данном случае сервер при возврате результата указал неправильную кодировку. Кодировка консоли тут ни при чем. И совет все строки декодировать в юникод работает только в том случае, если вы знаете в какой кодировке данные к вам пришли.